# How to delete a row in html table which is populated based on MySQL database values?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I am new to PHP,

I'm trying to delete a particular row in html table which is populated based on MySQL database values.

Every row in html table have return button, when I click on particular row return button it will deleting newly added row in database but.

Here is my Html & PHP code :

```
<?php

include('connection.php');

echo "
<tr>
<th>ID </th>
<th>Component Type </th>
<th>Component Name</th>
<th>Number of Components</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Phone</th>
<th>Company Name</th>
<th>Company Number</th>
<th>Alloted Date</th>
<th>Return</th>
</tr>";

$data=@$_POST['search'];

$sql = "select * from alloted_comp where emp_phone='$data'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
If (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        ?>
     <form action="" method="post">
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $id=$row['id']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $row['comp_type']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $row['comp_name']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $row['num_comp']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $row['emp_name']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $row['emp_phone']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['emp_compeny']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $row['emp_compeny_num']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Retun" name="submit" class="button">


            </td>              
        </tr>
       </form>
        <?php
    }
}

?>

<?php 

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

        if(isset($id)){
        $sql1="INSERT INTO prev_alloted_comp(id,emp_name,emp_phone,emp_compeny,emp_compeny_num,comp_type,comp_name,alloted_date) SELECT id,emp_name,emp_phone,emp_compeny,emp_compeny_num,comp_type,comp_name,date FROM alloted_comp WHERE id='$id'";
        $retval1 = mysql_query( $sql1, $con );        
            if(! $retval1 ) {
               die('Could not store data: ' . mysql_error());
            }



        $sql2="delete from alloted_comp where id='$id' ";
        $retval = mysql_query( $sql2, $con );        
            if(! $retval ) {
               die('Could not delete data: ' . mysql_error());
            }

            mysql_close($con);
          }

      }         
                ?>
```

Comment: 1. **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They are deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7. Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. **You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO. Specially since you're not escaping the user input at all.

Comment: Kiran first of all follow what Magnus Eriksson commented above and than I will help you in this.

Comment: AJAX is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Change your MySQL into MySQLi (I agree eith @Magnus Eriksson)

Further, You need to do 2 changes for that.

in HTML

```
<tr id="<?php echo $row['id];?>">
```

it will print

```
<tr id="1">
<tr id="2">
```

Then add Jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('tr').click(function(){
           var id = $(this).attr('id');

           // if we need to remove this row from only HTML
           $('tr#'+id).css('display', 'none');


           // if we need to remove from db
           $.ajax({
               url: '/del-record.php',
               type: 'POST',
               data: {id: id} 
           });
     });
});
```

if we need to delete record from db then we need to create a PHP File to delete record

```
<?php
     //include db connection

     $query = "delete from table where id = ".$_POST['id'];
     mysqli_query($query); // if using mysqli

     echo '1';
?>
```

Comment: why need ID attribure over there ?

Comment: What happen if not use id and write jQuery directly as **$(this).css('display', 'none');** ?

Comment: this will not delete the row from the DB

Comment: @CodeGodie : In title, author want to remove from html table.

Comment: @NaveedRamzan I may be wrong but i think they want it deleted from the DB as well: "_when i click on particular row return button it will deleting newly added row in database_"

Comment: @NaveedRamzan, as I asked, i think it work fine but sometimes (not sure) it maybe hide another rows so need to use id which traget the exact "TR" :)

Comment: @SoniVimal : Agreed :)

Comment: @CodeGodie, have you checked entire code at below, author code for delete on submit... so need to add it in jQuery.only perform populate the entire tr

Comment: @NaveedRamzan : Thank you